# Eliminate \xa0 return UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, xpath, unicode

I am getting data using Xpath and the output has `'\xa0'` which is Unicode. I wanted to eliminate it but it returns:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is my code:

```
page_active = requests.get('http://www.marketinout.com/stock-screener/stocks.php?list=volume_leaders&exch=asx')
active = html.fromstring(page_active.content)
data = active.xpath('//tbody/tr/td/text()')
data >>> [u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0Bard1 Life Sciences Limited                                                         

                                                                                                           ',
 u'\xa0Gold', u'\xa0Basic Materials', u'\xa0ASX', u'\xa07', u'\xa00.025', u'\xa00.015', u'\xa0150.0', u'\xa02
78,097,367', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0Patrys Ltd  ...]
```

In order to eliminate `'\xa0'`, I tried `[a.replace('\xa0',' ') for a in data]` but it returns:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also used `[a.decode('utf-8').replace("\xa0","") for a in data]` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `\xa0` is just a byte, not Unicode. ASCII encoded text is part of Unicode too.

Comment: `u'\xa0'` on the other hand is a Unicode string with the Latin-1 range codepoint U+00A0, which is outside of the ASCII range. `'\xa0'` is just a bytestring with a 0xA0 byte in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing bytes and Unicode, don't do that. Use Unicode string literals instead:

```
[a.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') for a in data]
```

Otherwise, Python will try to decode the byte string `'\xa0'` as ASCII, and 0xA0 is not a valid ASCII codepoint.

Alternatively, use `unicode.strip()` to remove trailing and leading whitespace; the U+00A0 codepoint counts as whitespace:

```
[a.strip() for a in data]
```

Comment: Thanks. But the answer has the 'u left. Is possible to remove that too? `[u' ', u' ', u' Bard1 Life Sciences Limited                                                                  
                                                                                                             
                                                                                                  ', u' Gold'
, u' Basic Materials', u' ASX', u' 7'..]`

Comment: @bkcollection: the `u` is a type indicator, not part of the text. You have a list of Unicode string objects.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to tell Python to interpret your strings as Unicode.**

To do this, add a `u` before your strings:

```
[a.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') for a in data]
```

Comment: Hi,It works but it unable to remove the 'u ` in the list [u' ', u' ', u' Bard1 Life Sciences Limited                                                                  
                                                                                                             
                                                                                                  ', u' Gold'
, u' Basic Materials', u' ASX', u' 7'..]`

Comment: @bkcollection: you don't want to remove the `u` prefixes, those indicate you have Unicode string objects. You **want** Unicode string objects.